# Alternative to AJAX Control Toolkit for doing AJAX file uploads via .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there an alternative to AJAX Control Toolkit in regards to doing AJAX file uploads in C#? Every time I try to upload a file using the toolkit it just returns a red "(error)". I guess .NET framework 4.5 is not supported?

Comment: did you try use third-party library like https://fineuploader.com/

Comment: I had a look at Fine Uploader earlier, but it appears that there is no support for .NET?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out:

In addition to the entry under system.web in web.config that everyone mentions, I also had to add the following under system.webServer: